# How to set different width for md-grid-tile

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use new Angular Material.
This code produce grid with two columns:

```
<md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="10">
  <md-grid-tile></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile></md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

How to set 20% width to first columns and remaning 80% to second?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
<md-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="2:1">
  <md-grid-tile colspan='2'>1</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile colspan='8'>2</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

you need to read this documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

[image]

Comment: What does mean? `rowHeight="2:1"`?

Comment: its a ration, column-width:row-height.

Comment: And how to set height?

Comment: i add an image above, describing how to set the row height.

Comment: Do you mean to use `rowHeight`? I tried to set it for header: `rowHeight="15"` and `rowHeight="5"` for others rows. It does not work

Comment: in the header you define the row height. In order to change it for other grid,
try to use rowSpan and colSpan, to manipulate the width and height for each grid.

Comment: Can you share example?

Comment: click on the < > button at the top right edge to view the source code :)

Comment: I have three columns in which the center one is an image and other two are buttons. I want to set as button1=20% image=60% button2=20%. But below code does not work and on screen nothing is shown. can someone help?

Comment: `  <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2"><button mat-button><</button></mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="6">
      <img [src]="dbImage" class="fit-image">
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2"><button mat-button>></button></mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>`

Answer (score 0):

[material.angularjs.org. mdGridTile](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridTile)

Tiles contain the content of an `md-grid-list`. They span one or more grid cells vertically or horizontally, and use `md-grid-tile-{footer,header}` to display secondary content.

```
 <md-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="2:1">

   <md-grid-tile colspan='2'>1 </md-grid-tile>

   <md-grid-tile colspan='8'>2 </md-grid-tile>

 </md-grid-list>
```

**md-row-height**

```
string
```

One of

CSS length - Fixed height rows (eg. `8px` or `1rem`)
`{width}:{height}` - Ratio of width to height (eg. `md-row-height`="16:9")
"`fit`" - Height will be determined by subdividing the available height by the number of rows

Comment: And how to set height?

Comment: `md-row-height` foe new Angular Material? Where to use it?

Comment: @Kondal The OP is asking for **`angular-material2`**, **NOT** **`angularjs-material`**! @Daniel